# What is the output of this C++ Program? chars are stored as ASCII values?

Tags: c++

```
char char_ = '3';
unsigned int * custom_mem_address = (unsigned int *) &char_;
cout<<char_<<endl;
cout << *custom_mem_address<<endl;
```

Since custom_mem_address contains one byte value of char '3', I except it to contain the ascii value of '3' which is 51.
But the output is the following.

3
1644042035

Depending on the byte alignment at least one byte in the 1644042035 should be 51 right? But its not. Can you please explain.

Can someone explain where am I wrong

Comment: Undeifned Behaviour is undefined. There is no 'should' for UB.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen True. But there are things that are far more likely than others.

Comment: If you use base 16 instead of base 10 you might see something.

Comment: fwiw you can get a little more certainty of whats going on if you `char char_ = 51;`

Comment: What's the size of `int` on your machine? Given that most PCs are 64-bit nowadays, it won't be large enough to contain a memory address. `(unsigned int *) &` will mangle the character's address.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. Int pointer is different from int. int pointer will always hold the address irrespective of the size.

Comment: The output of this C++ program **should** be the instructor rapping your typing knuckles with a ruler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1644042035 in binary is `0110 0001 1111 1110 0001 0111 0011 0011` and 51 is `0011 0011`.

0110 0001 1111 1110 0001 0111 **0011 0011**

0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 **0011 0011**

Isn't that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks. My bad. Should have compared in hex for easy analysis.